# Can't download Django throught terminal

Tags: python, django, pip

I am trying to download and install Django through the terminal. To do this I ran this command:

```
sudo pip install Django
```

However, this produced the following error:

```
Collecting Django
  Downloading Django-2.0.tar.gz (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 121kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-Y1GrsP/Django/setup.py", line 32, in 
<module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/tmp/pip-build-Y1GrsP/Django/
```

Answer (score 6):

Django 2.0 is not compatible with versions of Python less than 3.4

`lru_cache()` was introduced in Python 3.2, so the version of Python you're using is too old.

If you need to support an Python 2.7, try Django 1.11, as this was the last version to support it:

```
pip install "django~=1.11.9"
```

Comment: I'd also highly recommend learning and loving how to use a `virtualenv` - installing alongside the system Python brought me to tears!